# How to populate a cell with a value depending on the selections made in two dropdown lists

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a number of worksheets with years (2022, 2023, 2024 etc.)
In each sheet are months in merged cells (A3-D3=Jan, E3-H3=Feb, I3-L3=Mar etc).
Below each month is a heading for Date (A4) and Fund Types (B4=Conservative, C4=Balanced & D4=Growth).
Below "Date" are the dates ie. 01/01/23 - 31/01/23
Below the Fund Types are amounts ie. $100

On a separate sheet named "Front Page" I'd ideally want two dropdowns, one for "date" and the other for the fund type (B4=Conservative, C4=Balanced & D4=Growth). eg:

- On sheet "2023" The amount under B4=Conservative and the date is A5=01-01-23 is $100. Under C4 and the same date is $200 therefore:
- I need one drop down to select the date (A5)
- The next drop down to select the Fund Type (B4,C4 or D4)
- Then as a result of the selections made above, a cell is populated with the corresponding amount $200 if A5 and B4 is selected then $100 if the Fund type dropdown is changed to C4 etc.

I hope that makes sense!

Comment: Examples would be beneficial. Can you either take screenshots where formulas are displayed or upload and provide a link to a copy of your workbook.